# Sort order for items starting with a number

Tags: cme

The content managers at the company where I work nowadays use numeric prefixes to order folders and structure groups (and also for navigation). I notice that items which have a title starting with a number, sometimes come BEFORE items starting with a letter, and sometimes AFTER. 
I have 3 environments to check this on, one 2009 GA, one 2009 SP1 and one 2011 SP1. The results are:
2009 GA: numbers come BEFORE letters
2009 SP1: numbers come AFTER letters
2011 SP1: numbers come AFTER letters

My question is: how can this difference be explained? Was the logic in Tridion changed in 2009 SP1? Or is it related to the locale of the server? Or is there another explanation?

My preference by the way would be to have numbers before letters.

Comment: Are all the databases the same on those environments? I have seen differences in Ordering between MS SQL Server and Oracle before (where dev was on MS SQL server and prod was on Oracle)

Comment: Yes +1 for SQL Server and Oracle differences

Comment: >> 2011 SP1: numbers come AFTER letters -> Not on my instance of 2011 SP1, numbers come first.

Comment: Check that the dialect/language is the same on all the DBs.

Comment: The SQL vs Oracle hypothesis sounds plausible. I don't know which DB is used in my 2009 GA system (which puts numbers before letters), the other two are definitely Oracle. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, the order is alphabetical. As others have mentioned, this will depend on the collation sequence of the database.

Answer (score 4):

I worked with SDL Tridion 2009, 2009 SP1, 2011 and 2011 SP1 it came as expected on all these - Numbers comes first and then the letters (I remembers it as it was a requirement for us)

I may be silly in asking this but If you are looking at the right pane after selecting the concerned folder/structure group in the left pane, ensure it is not sorted in descending order by Name.

See the image below:
[image]

Also, check the Locale and Language of your SDL Tridion (in the user preference if it is making any difference) and on the Servers.

Comment: I have not sorted on any column, this is how Tridion presents the items originally

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the same issue in our SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 implementation.We use Oracle 11g. What we found is that there is one environment lcmAcc that behaves the correct way. Means that it sorts first numbers and then letters. After testing and connecting different DB's (all Oracle 11g) we concluded that is not a DB issue but a setting on the Server. Whatever DB we connect with the lcmAcc (windows server) environment behaves as we want. Could it be a Tridion configuration setting that does the job or the Oracle client installed there? Can anybody give us a tip. As I see the question was asked a year ago. Quirijn did you figured it out?